# If $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P(}\{1,2,\ldots,n\})$ then exists disjoint $I,J\subset\mathcal{F}$ so that $\bigcup_{X\in I} X=\bigcup_{Y\in J} Y$.

Tags: alternative-proof, independence

> Let $n>0$ and $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n+1}$
> are nonempty subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
> Prove that there exists two nonempty disjoint subsets $I$ and $J$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ such that
> $$\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i=\bigcup_{j\in J} X_j$$
> China Western Mathematical Olympiad 2002

Say $v_i$ is indicator vector for the set $X_i$. So, if $X_1= \{1,4,5\}$ then $v_1= (1,0,0,1,1,0,0,...,0,0)$.

Clearly $v_1,...v_{n+1}$ are not independant in $\mathbb{Q}^n$. So there are scalars, not all $0$, such that $$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$$  Let $P$ be a set of indices of positive scalars and $N$ of negative one, so $P\cap N = \emptyset$. Then we have $$\sum_{i\in P} a_iv_i = -\sum_{j\in N} a_jv_j$$

Now let $\mathcal{P} := \bigcup_{i\in P} X_i$ and $\mathcal{N} := \bigcup_{j\in N} X_j$. It is enough to prove $\mathcal{P}= \mathcal{N}$ and we are done.

If $k\in \mathcal{P}$, then $k$-th coordinate of at least one $v_i$,   $i\in P $ is not $0$, but then $k$-th coordinate of sum $-\sum_{j\in N} a_jv_j$  is also not zero, so there must be a vector $v_j$,   $j\in N $ with nonzero $k$-th coordinate, so $k\in \mathcal{N}$ and thus $\mathcal{P}\subseteq \mathcal{N}$, since $k$ was arbitrary. Since the other inclusion is now also obivous the claim is proven.

Comment: What is your question? The problem you quoted easily follows from the counting argument: there are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, but there are $2^{n+1}$ distinct subsets $I\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$. So, by the pigeonhole principle, some two of $I$'s them should have the same $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$.

Comment: Ok, would you go and write it as an answer? @MaxAlekseyev

Comment: I'm still not sure what is your question. Please formulate it.

Comment: I just want an alternative solution, see the tag. @MaxAlekseyev

Comment: In the title, the $X_i$ are subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$; in the question, they aresubsets of of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Which is right?

Comment: @Aqua The title specifies that $I,J$ should be among $n+1$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ while the quoted text does not have this restriction. The answer by Max Alekseyev and your proof do not fit that restriction.